# How to close the webpage URL?

Tags: java

I have opened using

```
Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
desktop.browse(new URI("https://www.google.co.in"));
```

It will launch the Google webpage by default in chrome browser, but need to know how to close the launch URL.

Comment: what you mean with `close the launch url` ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Closing a Web Browser for a specific URL from the java program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075997/closing-a-web-browser-for-a-specific-url-from-the-java-program)

Comment: @JordiCastilla  Once webpage has launched in browser i need to close that

Comment: @WaiHaLee Is there any ways to launch the Webpage & close it?

Comment: @senthilvel — the answer was **in** [the link I gave](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075997/closing-a-web-browser-for-a-specific-url-from-the-java-program) - it doesn't look like it's possible.

Comment: @WaiHaLee  How I need to execute that & whether I need to execute all three programs??
Advance Thx for ur help :)

Comment: If you leave a downvote, please explain to me, why you downvoted, so I can improve my answer/take your point into consideration for future answers.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, and even if you somehow will make out a way by making custom methods i.e hacking , it will break at some point of time in future.

Comment: Is there any ways to launch the Webpage & close it in JAVA without using SeleniumWebdriver?
Advance Thx for ur help :)

Comment: @senthilvel sorry not much aware about that :)