# To close a specific browser in java

Tags: java, browser

I need to close a specific opened browser. I have opened the browser using below code in one class and want to close it from another class. What can be the way, I don'nt want to use runtime as its slow.

```
Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
dt.browse(  new URI(url) );
```

Comment: Take a look to [Closing a Web Browser for a specific URL from the java program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075997/closing-a-web-browser-for-a-specific-url-from-the-java-program)

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356340/killing-a-process-using-java) can help you