# Java URL open and Close after random time

Tags: java, url, time

I need code that will open url and close it after some random time(3-10minutes)

Something like:

```
    Desktop d = Desktop.getDesktop();
    d.browse(new URI("http://google.pl"));
    d.wait(1000);
    d.destroy();  //error there is no destroy function here
```

any ideas?

Comment: You could make a thread for the URI, then terminate it after a period of time.

Comment: Thanks it helped a lot, but browser still isn't closing after thread terminate :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Closing a Web Browser for a specific URL from the java program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075997/closing-a-web-browser-for-a-specific-url-from-the-java-program)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into this some more, the `Desktop` class does not have a `close()` feature to it.

If you want to launch another program via Java you should use the `Process` class. Doing something similar to this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
public class Process {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process process = runTime.exec("notepad");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            process.destroy();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, what to paste here:  
    runTime.exec("notepad"); to run opera and url?

Comment: Ok doesnt matter, got it :)